# Proof exercise that the cardinal number of a set in $\mathbb R^2$ is $\frak c$ [Edited]

Tags: elementary-set-theory

let $S \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ be a countable set.

and $a \in \mathbb R^2 \setminus S$

Show that the Cardinal number of the set of lines ($y=mx+n$) in $\mathbb R^2$ that passes through point $a$ but don't cross S is $\frak c$.

What I did so far:I called the set of lines  in $\mathbb R^2$ that passes through point $a$ and crosses S, with M, and the set of lines that does not with P.
and L the set of all the lines in R that passes through a.

and so $P \cup M = L$ , and by my previous exercise I already proved that for sets such as L it's cardinal number is $\frak c$. And I know from a sentence proved in class that the cardinal number of the union of a set with a cardinal number of $\frak c$ is also $\frak c$. And from this point on I don't have an idea on how to prove that set M's cardinal number is $\frak c$. If anyone has a better idea of how to prove this, I'd be happy to hear. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. I'll assume that your definition of cardinality is that two sets have the same cardinality if there exists an injection both ways (or that you know the Cantor-Bernstein-Schröder theorem).

You probably know that cardinal subtraction isn't well defined, but if it was it would be easy to see that $|\mathbb R| - |\mathbb Z| = |\mathbb R|$. This follows from the fact that a interval in $\mathbb R$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb R$.

However we can use this idea anyway, because we don't need that subtraction is unique in general. What we need is only that if $A$ and $B$ are **disjoint** subsets of $X$ we have $|X\setminus A|=|X\setminus B|$. To see this we can partition $X$ into $X\setminus (A\cup B)$, $A$ and $B$ (and these are of course also components of a partition of $X\setminus A$ and $X\setminus B$), we of course has an injection from $X\setminus (A\cup B)$ into itself, also we have injections from $A$ to $B$ and from $B$ to $A$. These can be used to form an injection form $X\setminus A$ to $X\setminus B$ and vice versa.

Now consider $\mathbb R$ and a countable $A\subset\mathbb R$, now since intervals in $\mathbb R$ aren't countable we have for each unit interval at least one number not in $A$, so we have a sequence $x_j$ such that $j < x_j < j+1$ such that $x_j\notin A$ and let $B = \{x_j\}$. Now $A$ and $B$ are disjoint sets of the same cardinality so $|\mathbb R \setminus A|$ = $|\mathbb R \setminus B$, but $\mathbb R\setminus B$ contains intervals and therefor have the same cardinality as $\mathbb R$.

This means that if $|L|=\frak c$ and $|M| = \aleph_0$ we have that $|L\setminus M|=\frak c$